# Can't open namespaces in a Nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, nuget, nuget-package, type-providers

I did the following:

1. Create a new F# project in VS2013
2. In Package Manager Console, execute while targetting the new project:

   ```
   Install-Package FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider
   ```
3. In the file, type:

   ```
   open FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider
   ```

...as can be seen in the examples included in the Github project.

But I get the error:

"The namespace or module 'FSharp' is not defined"

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Nuget, and this is the first package I've downloaded that hasn't "just work"ed.

Comment: That should just work, I have tested it on my machine. Did you install the package into the correct project? Does your F# project now have a reference to `FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider` ?

Comment: Are you working in an F# source file (`*.fs`) or in an F# script (`*.fsx`) ?

Comment: @DaveShaw Yes (only project in solution) and Yes, that and the other libraries are displayed in the References folder

Comment: @TomasPetricek I tried it in the default Library1.fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project was targeting .NET framework 4.5 by default. It needed to be targeting 4.5.1.